# How to secure drupal file with permission?

Tags: linux, security, drupal, permissions, drupal-7

i'm asking what's the best linux permission to drupal files in the purpose to secure it.
My setting.php is under 444 but the others are 755 .
Thank you

Comment: There's no way to accurately answer this question without knowing: what user does the webserver run as (www-data, su_php, etc.)? What groups are on the server? How do you update the site's code?

Comment: the server user is www-data, and im updating the modules and themes via the http installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

440 is fine for the settings file. For the others do:

Navigate to sites/default folder:

```
chown -R :www-data files
```

Then give you and web server read/write permission to files folder ('s' makes the files inside the directory inherit these permissions.)

```
chmod g+ws files
```

If you need to overwrite previous created files' permissions do (navigate to sites/default/files):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Now your web server can read/write but not execute files in the files directory.

Comment: Thank you very much.. and what about the other files, i mean the modules or the core or sites/all folders??

Comment: There is a [Linux section](http://drupal.org/node/244924) showing and explaining files permissions for the whole Drupal install.

Comment: Thank you very much I will throw an eye on it

Comment: Maybe look into the [Security Review module](http://drupal.org/project/security_review).

Comment: The problem is that when i give the 664 permission to the "files" folder i don't see photos and media anymore

Answer (score 2):

Once finished editing the settings.php file, you should change it to 440 giving only you and the webserver read-only access.